# Linter sort-imports - Imports should be sorted alphabetically

Tags: eslint

I'm getting the following error from linter...

```
error    Imports should be sorted alphabetically    sort-imports
```

And here are my imports:

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { Widget } from '../../interfaces/Widget';
```

Aren't they already sorted? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the capitalization of the W in "Widget". If "Widget" were in lowercase, "widget", the sorting works just fine.

You can change the eslint rule for ignorecase to get around this:

```
"ignoreCase": true
```